# Avoid using capturing groups in locale regular expression test?

Tags: php, regex, locale

Regular expression only for checking only if the string is valid, not for capturing any part of it:

> ISO 639-1 two-letter lowercase culture code and an ISO 3166-1 two-letter uppercase subculture code, or a ISO 639-1 lowercase culture code by itself.

That is `it`, `it-IT` for example. I ended up (I'm not so good in regular expression) with this:

```
^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?$
```

Using the capturing group (the 3166-1 part). Is the group really needed? How can avoid using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
^[a-z]{2}(?:-[A-Z]{2})?$
```

To define non-capturing group you use `(?:)`

Comment: Thanks. So the group is really needed for grouping `-` sign and the two uppercase letter code?

Comment: yeah, I cannot think of any other way to do it